# Show that rational affine topological conjugation of two-adics is closed to periodicity, or give a counterexample.

Tags: dynamical-systems, p-adic-number-theory, topological-groups

Let $f_{a,b}(x)=ax-b\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}$ be a function on the field of 2-adic numbers $\Bbb Q_2$ parametrized by the pair of 2-adic units $a,b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times$

Then quantifying over $a,b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times$ all $f_{a,b}(x)$ are topologically conjugate to each other over $\Bbb Q_2$, and are in fact topologically conjugate to the [tent map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map#Behaviour) with parameter $\mu=2$ and the logistic map with parameter $r=4$.

Let $T_{a,b}(x)$ be the unique function that topologically conjugates $f_{a,b}(x)$ to $f_{1,1}(x)$

Then $T_{1,1}(x)$ is the identity of all such $T$ under composition - it composes with any given $T_{a,b}(x)$ to leave it unchanged.  Let $(T,\circ)$ be the group of all such $T$ under composition.

Now restrict $a,b$ to 2-adic units which are eventually periodic.  I believe that restriction forms a subgroup $S$ although I do not yet have a proof that it is closed under composition.

The action of $S$ is what I refer to in the question title as "rational affine topological conjugation of two-adics."

I believe that the action of $S$ is closed to periodic 2-adic numbers, i.e. for all eventually periodic 2-adic numbers $x$, the action of $S$ on $x$ generates only 2-adic numbers which are themselves also eventually periodic.

I'm sure this must be eminently provable.  Can you prove it, or provide a counterexample?

A proof of this would prove and significantly generalise Lagarias' [periodicity conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#cite_note-Lagarias_(1985)-3).